# how do I change and delete the height and color of the particular section in a ms word template?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-template

I have downloaded a ms word resume template but unable to change the height and color of a particular predefined background section.
[image: This is the Image I have attached]

I want to change the height and color of that particular section which I have highlighted in my attachment.

I am attaching the link of the word document here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By3INf6Hdyb-NmNwTWlOUHJiVFk

Any Suggestion will be indeed very helpful ..!
Thank You..!

Comment: What about `Insert` --> `Header` --> `Edit header` ?

Comment: Yup it works..! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`Insert` --> `Header` --> `Edit header`
```